# Insertion of data violates the foreign key constraint

Tags: postgresql, database-design, foreign-key, insert

Consider I have two tables `Employee` and `Department` with the fields given below:

**Employee:**

Fname, Minit, Lname, *`Ssn`* Bdate, Address, Sex, Salary, Super_ssn, Dno

**Department:**

*`Dname`*, *`Dnumber`*, Mgr_ssn, Mgr_start_date

*`Italics and code block`* represent the primary key of table.

In above case, **Super_Ssn** references the **SSN** of employee, while **Dno** references the Department's **Dnumber**.
Creating the sql for them is pretty straightforward by adding columns first and altering them later when both tables are formed. However, while inserting the data like given below:

```
insert into employee values('James','E','Borg','888665555','1937-11-10','asda','M',55000,NULL,1);
ERROR:  insert or update on table "employee" violates foreign key constraint "dno_ref_dnum_dpt"
DETAIL:  Key (dno)=(1) is not present in table "department".
```

and

```
insert into sp0090.department values ('Headquarter',1,'888665555','1981-06-19');
ERROR:  insert or update on table "department" violates foreign key constraint "department_mgr_ssn_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (mgr_ssn)=(888665555) is not present in table "employee".
```

I am getting the foreign key constraint violated. This can be traced because to insert **Mgr_ssn** in **department**, it has to exists in Employee and to insert **dno** in **Employee** it has to exists in **Department**. However, I am required to fill the tables with maintaining the schema as it is. How do I solve this circular referencing? Thanks.

Comment: Can you share a SQL for Deferred or CTE? Thanks

Comment: You might want to have a look at this link : http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/102903/is-it-acceptable-to-have-circular-foreign-key-references-how-to-avoid-them

Answer (score 7):

In Postgres, there are two ways to circumvent the chicken-and-egg problem of inserting into tables with circular references.

a) Defer one of the constraints, either declaring it as `DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED` when created or as `DEFERRABLE` as created and then defer it when needed.

For an example of using deferrable constraints, see my answer in this question:
  [Implementation of a many-to-many relationship with total participation constraints in SQL.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/127107/implementation-of-a-many-to-many-relationship-with-total-participation-constrain)

b) Use a single statement to insert into the two (or more) tables, using modifying CTEs. Example for your case:

```
with
  insert_emp as
  ( insert into employee 
        (Fname, Minit, Lname, Ssn, Bdate, Address, Sex, Salary, Super_ssn, Dno)
    values
        ('James', 'E', 'Borg', '888665555', '1937-11-10', 'asda', 'M', 55000, NULL, 1)
    returning 
        *
  ), 
  insert_dep
  ( insert into sp0090.department 
        (Dname, Dnumber, Mgr_ssn, Mgr_start_date) 
    values 
        ('Headquarter', 1, '888665555', '1981-06-19')
    returning 
        *
  ) 
select *
from insert_emp as e
  full join insert_dep as d
  on  e.dno = d.dnumber
  and e.ssn = d.mgr_ssn ;
```

Answer (score 3):

There is an old article that explains this situation, this is called a circular reference. When inserting or deleting rows from the two table, you'll run into the "chicken-and-egg" problem. Which table should I insert first - without violating any constraint? I would suggest reading this article below and seeing if it helps.

[SQL By Design: The Circular Reference](http://sqlmag.com/querying/sql-design-circular-reference)

Comment: Nice and the article is relevant. But it is mainly about SQL Server. Postgres has implemented `DEFERRED` constraints that can solve the issue of inserting and updating into tables with circular references.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the heads up I wasn't aware of this.