# Is it possible to insert cyclic foreign keys that are AUTO INCREMENT primary keys?

Tags: postgresql, foreign-key

I am trying to model a quiz structure, where there are questions and a unlimited number of answers, where only one is correct.

**Example:**

1. Question A

   1. Answer A
   2. Answer B
   3. **Answer C** (Correct Answer)
   4. Answer D
2. Question B

   1. Answer A
   2. **Answer B** (Correct Answer)

Given the requirements I came with the following structure:

```sql
CREATE TABLE question (
  id int PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
  correct_answer_id int NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE answer (
  id int PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
  question_id int NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE question ADD CONSTRAINT q_a_fk
  FOREIGN KEY (correct_answer_id) REFERENCES answer(id);

ALTER TABLE answer ADD CONSTRAINT a_q_fk
  FOREIGN KEY (question_id) REFERENCES question(id);
```

However I am having problems inserting data. Is it possible to insert this structure via a `CTE` or `deferrable FK` within a transaction?

Edit: I would like to guarantee that no question is inserted without a correct answer.

Comment: Very similar to this one: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/102903/is-it-acceptable-to-have-circular-foreign-key-references-how-to-avoid-them

Answer (score 1):

Cyclic FK constraints are always a problem.

One way to deal with this, is to fetch the "next ID" manually using `nextval()`. In order to not hardcode the underlying sequence names, `pg_get_serial_sequence()` can be used (which also works with `identity` columns, despite its name).

```
with new_ids (question_id, answer_id) as (
  select nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('question', 'id')), 
         nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('answer', 'id'))
), new_question as (
  insert into question (id, content, correct_answer_id)
  select question_id, 'The Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything', answer_id
  from new_ids
)
insert into answer (id, content, question_id)
select answer_id, '42', question_id
from new_ids;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZDoSBejN)

But still, I would try to get rid of the cyclic dependency. In my opinion the hassle to work with this setup is a bigger problem than the fact that you can't ensure that at least one correct answer exists.

Comment: Would you still ignore that a question may not have a correct answer even if is a domain rule? In my opinion a "QuizQuestion" shouldn't be able to be inserted in the database without a correct answer. I know sometimes we can't represent all rules at database level, so my options here are: remove this cyclic FK and allow questions without correct answers (this will be a bug, need to validate at backend); have the hassle to work with cyclic FKs but have data correctness; or a different db model that only allows questions with a correct answer (which TBH I can't figure).

Answer (score 0):

You should rearrange your design so that you instead have an `is_correct` flag on the `answer` table.

You can enforce a unique correct answer by using a `UNIQUE NULLS DISTINCT` constraint, keeping the `is_correct` column either `TRUE` or `NULL`.

```sql
CREATE TABLE question (
  id int PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY
);

CREATE TABLE answer (
  id int PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
  question_id int NOT NULL,
  is_correct boolean NULL CHECK (is_correct = TRUE),
  UNIQUE NULLS DISTINCT (question_id, is_correct)
);

ALTER TABLE answer ADD CONSTRAINT a_q_fk
  FOREIGN KEY (question_id) REFERENCES question(id);
```

You could also do this with a filtered unique index, which is also useful for DBMSs which do not support `NULLS DISTINCT`.

For example in SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE answer (
  id int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
  question_id int NOT NULL,
  is_correct bit NOT NULL,
  INDEX one_correct UNIQUE (question_id) INCLUDE (is_correct) WHERE (is_correct = 1)
);
```

Comment: In Postgres you would use `create unique index on answer (question_id) where is_correct` for the unique index (and define `is_correct` as NOT NULL).

Comment: This was my first approach, however I think I cannot guarantee that there is at least one correct answer (let's ignore the unique index for now) at the database level. I can create questions without correct answers.

Comment: Yes true, you can have a deferrable constraint for that, but that brings its own issues.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I know you can, but I think a `NULLS DISTINCT` unique constraint is cleaner. There doesn't seem to be any major difference.

Comment: Well you'll have to deal with `null` values in `is_correct` - you are essentially replacing `false` with `null`  which I find much uglier